# Convert Date String to Date in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I need some help with this. I have database with a column for start and end with a value format `Fri Feb 21 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)` an store in varchar. I want to convert it to date in **MySQL** query.

I've tried using **str_to_date()** but there is no luck.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Fri Feb 21 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)','%a %M %e %Y %H:%i:%s');
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('Fri Feb 21 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)','%a %M %e %Y %H:%i:%s') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-02-21 00:00:00                                                                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I've tried that one but using this Fri Feb 21 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time). no luck.

Comment: Working for that string too. Updated my answer.